# laravel 5.2 redirect with message

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-blade

if user of site visits /page, I want him to redirect to index with message. How do I access redirect message in view? My routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'],function(){ 
     Route::get('/page', function () {
         return redirect('/')->withMessage(["warning"=> ["yeah","test"]]); // According official docs, this should work.
     }); 
     Route::get('/', 'Page@front');
});
```

My Page controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\News;
use App\PageContact;
use Session;

class Page extends Controller{
    public function front(Request $Request){
        return view('index')->withNews("news");
}
```

**important:** yes, my pages are already wrapped in web middleware. And please avoid posting Laravel 3 or Laravel 4 solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
->with('warning', 'testing')
```

Then in the view:

```
@if(session()->has('warning'))
    {!! session()->get('warning') !!}
@endif
```

Comment: You were right except the one thing - $warning is not declared like that, therefore cannot be accessed in views. Instead, you can retrieve variable with session()->get('warning') instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from user2094178 is correct, but you don't have to use

```
->with('warning', 'testing')
```

it can also be (as you did):

```
->withNews("news");
->withWarning('testing');
```

Since the View-class is using the magic function "__call":

```
     /**
     * Dynamically bind parameters to the view.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
            return $this->with(Str::snake(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
        }

        throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on view.");
    }
```